# How to import such data in python 3.0 using genfromtxt

Tags: python, numpy, import, genfromtxt

I am using

```
genfromtxt('84MHZN01.TBL',delimiter='\t',dtype=None,skip_header=41,skip_footer=2)
```

to import the data like

```
[ b'-0.300000       0.00000      9.052297E+00  0.000000E+00  9.052297E+00  0.000000E+00'
 b'-7.700000E-02   0.00000      9.066407E+00  0.000000E+00  9.066407E+00  0.000000E+00'
 b'0.146000       0.00000      9.107430E+00  0.000000E+00  9.107430E+00  0.000000E+00'
 b'0.369000       0.00000      9.168216E+00  0.000000E+00  9.168216E+00  0.000000E+00'
 b'0.592000       0.00000      9.241816E+00  0.000000E+00  9.241816E+00  0.000000E+00'
 b'0.815000       0.00000      9.319924E+00  0.000000E+00  9.319924E+00  0.000000E+00'
 b'1.03800       0.00000      9.395081E+00  0.000000E+00  9.395081E+00  0.000000E+00']
```

I am try to use delimiter='  ', but not work. Shows error.
How could I import the data with separate Tab or space?
Also how to remove the b'?
Thanks,

Comment: A tab is `'\t'`, not `'/t'`.  Is that a copy/paste error?  If not, it might be your problem.

Comment: yes, type error in web. it is ' \t ' in code.

Comment: Does it work without the delimiter parameter.  The default is whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

In order to take the answer given by hpaulj and write there a correct answer, you need to delimit your data by whitespace.

But, if you read the [doc](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) to better understand how you can use genfromtxt, the withespace is the default parameter of delimiter setting.

So, you just have to write :

```
data = np.genfromtxt('84MHZN01.TBL',dtype=None,skip_header=41,skip_footer=2)
```

And you will obtain what you want ;)